# Best approach for retrieving data in a nested 1-to-many relationship

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have the following models: Client, Device and Revision

Cliente has many Device, and Device has many Revision

I want to retrieve all the latest revisions from a Client. I know I can use recursive=2 in client and I will get revisions like this:

```
$client['Client']['Device'][$i]['Revision'] //(array of revisions)
```

What I actually want is getting the latest revisions like these:

```
$client['Client']['Revision'][$i] //(array of revisions)
$client['Client']['Revision'][$i]['Device'] //and I may see the device like this. I know this is duplicated info, but the order is pretty much different.
```

I know there are plenty of ways of doing it. Much of the ones I think involve using direct SQL or processing the arrays, but is there actually a method that may be able to do this by just passing parameters?

I also thought of first getting all the device_id of a certain client, and the find all revisions where device_id IN (device1_id, device2_id, ...), but I don't really this, thought, not sure if there is a better way.